# Should Door Trim/Jamb be flush cut with bottom of base for carpet install?

Tags: carpet, baseboard

I'm finishing a room that will have new carpet installed. I plan to install the baseboard height about 1/2" off the slab so carpet can flow underneath. The room is all painted (trim/walls), but no base is installed. My question is: should I cut the closet/doors trim/jambs at 1/2" as well (before base install) so the carpet can flow under or is it not a big deal? The carpet will be about 5/8" thick and 1/2" pad, uncompressed.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Casing and base should both be at he same level. From the picture there are a couple of ways to cut it if you want to cut it (I'm not sure it's necessary, the carpet should hide the difference). You can get a trim saw that is designed to cut casings for floor installation, should be able to rent, it's probably too expensive to buy for just one job. If it were me, I'd carefully cut it with one of the Japanese back cut saws. The make really clean cuts and are very easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I always hold casing to the same height as the base trim (3/8" or 7/16" is enough--1/2" risks showing a gap with thinner carpets). However, if the casing is already installed, don't bother making cuts now. Carpet layers can easily deal with that situation by tucking against it. It shouldn't be a visual concern.

Comment: Yes casing is installed but I figure after I install base I'll never be able to cut the jamb properly. Current carpet is about 5/8" and 1/2" pad, uncompressed. All squished down the carpet will be maybe 3/8" and no pad under the base but going from just over an inch to 3/8" seems tight

Comment: The base being there doesn't really change anything. You'll use a handsaw or an undercut saw, neither of which care about the base trim.

Comment: I was thinking it would be hard to cut it flush without tagging the base if I did it afterwards but good point. Besides the carpet will land above the bottom of the base so should hide any slight imperfections